# Listview item colour

Tags: android

How to change colour of an the particular item in listview?

Comment: do you want to change color on click event or just set color on first display?pls elaborate

Comment: Please elaborate your question. Would you want to change the color on a particular event or something? Have you implemented your custom adapter for your list?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the condition under which you want to change color, you can define your list color as a ColorStateList (either in code or using a  in XML). See the [documentation on Color State List Resource](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.html).